# enter username and password in a batch script

Tags: batch

I run the below code that is log in to a server and after login, it's enter 1 and go to the next line but after that, I need to enter the username and password.
help me to complete the code.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
cd \Users\Abhinav Thakur\Downloads
start putty.exe -ssh -pw password Username@IPAddr
%SendKeys% "1" 
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"
goto :EOF
@end 
// JScript section
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: Not an answer to your actual question as it stands. But you should really use public key authentication, not username/password for that kind of scenario. It's not only much more secure, but also easier to handle.

Answer (score -1):

```cmd
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
START CHROME "www.google.com"
rem -- the script only works if the application in question is the active window. Set a timer to wait for it to load!
timeout /t 10
rem -- use the tab key to move the cursor to the login and password inputs. Most htmls interact nicely with the tab key being pressed to access quick links.
rem %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
rem now you can have it send the actual username/password to input box
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "username"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "password"
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"

REM -- goto :EOF

@end
// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```